# Why is the text displayed if the tag is missing in the xml?

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

You need to read the xml and display only those values where there are INNYL or INNFL tags. But if I do not have any of them in the "Document" or it is empty, then the output is: INNYL INNFL
Why is that? I need nothing to be displayed in this case, since there are no values (there is no tag or it is empty).

```
 def person = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("C:\\test\\test.xml"))

        person.Document.findAll { p ->
            p.Org.@INNYL != null ||
            p.IPV.@INNFL != null
        }.each { p ->
            println "INNYL ${p.Org.@INNYL} INNFL ${p.IPV.@INNFL}"
        }
```

I didn't attach XML, as you can create any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `@INNYL` returns an empty attribute, not null...  You can check it by getting the text, and check if they're empty

```
    person.Document.findAll { p ->
        p.Org.@INNYL.text() ||
        p.IPV.@INNFL.text()
    }.each { p ->
        println "INNYL ${p.Org.@INNYL} INNFL ${p.IPV.@INNFL}"
    }
```

Or you can use `isEmpty()` , ie: `!p.Org.@INNYL.isEmpty()`